# What is the simplest way to return different content types based on the extension in the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, rest, format

I'd like to be able to change the extension of a url and recieve the model in a different format.

e.g. if

```
/products/list
```

returns a html page containing a list of products, then

```
/products/list.json
```

would return them in a json list.

***Note:*** *I like the simplicity of the [ASP.NET MVC REST SDK](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/08/17/rest-for-mvc.aspx), it only requires about 5 lines of code to hook it in, but the format is specified as a query string parameter i.e. `/products/list?format=json` which is not what I want, I could tweak this code if there are no other options, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog post that shows one possible example. It's a tiny bit complicated, but might work for your needs.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/06/handling-formats-based-on-url-extension.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use routes in conjunction with the rest sdk

Comment: Do you know how? I know that it is possible if I tweak the SDK code, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the flexibility to drop Apache or something similar in front of your service, you can always use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite an external `http://products/list.json` into `http://products/list?format=json` which your framework can render more easily.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "list.json", you could choose "list/json" and use a route like

{controller}/{action}/{id}

Then ProductController.List would be called, with an ID parameter of "json". The .List() action then would decide whether or not to return an HTML view or JSON content.

Comment: that wouldn't work for an index action e.g. /products and /products/json